# Why some variables can't display by message in cmake?

Tags: variables, cmake, message

I am using cmake to build my project. When I want to check some variables, I use message(${}), however I find some vars can't display using message(), giving a error "message called with incorrect number of arguments". For example, I use "message(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})" to check the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH,
but is gives an error "message called with incorrect number of arguments". So how do I correctly check these kinds of vars in cmake?

Answer (score 1):

`${VAR}` expands the contents of the variable. If the variable contains spaces, it will count as multiple arguments. I think what you want is to print the value as a string by doing `message("${VAR}")`.

Comment: when I add "" to ${VAR} in message(), the output is a blank line, and other variables also show a blank line. Are these variable actually empty? I don't think so.

Comment: `Are these variable actually empty?` Yes.

Comment: Use the variable INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES as an example,
I am not sure if it is empty, so I write the following code in CMakeListx.txt:
include_directories(/root/include)
message("${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
the output of message is also a blank line, but the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES at least has one member since I used include_directories(), so how can I explain this result? What happend in detail?

Comment: I would have to see your cmake file. Regardless, that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Daniel: "... but the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES at least has one member since I used include_directories()" - The command [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) sets directory **property** [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html), not a **variable**. For print the property's value, you need first to extract this property into some variable. E.g., a directory property can be extracted using [get_directory_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_directory_property.html) command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, Finally I figure out how it works

Answer (score 0):

As an example, my CMakeLists.txt is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Trade)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(/root/include)
message("${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")

add_executable(Trade src/main.cpp)
```

Comment: The out put of message is just a blank line, I wonder why the variable can't be displayed properly?Though INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is a list, it has at least one member since I used include_directories() before.